# Где найти библиотеки для работы с графикой в Astra Linux Смоленск?

Tags: графика, поиск-библиотек, astra-linux

Нет возможности работать с графикой в Astra Linux Смоленск. Не хватает библиотек - аналогов QtChart, QtScatterSeries.

Где найти библиотеки для организации работы с графикой и как их установить?

Comment: У астры ядро дебиан, поэтому подойдёт любая либа, которая работает например, в убунту. Посмотрите в сторону qwt https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man3/qwtinstall.3.html

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/211204/

Comment: У вас Astra SE, в ней нет расширений типа QChart, насколько я помню. Дистрибутив на чем? В сети пишут про то, что нужен диск со средствами разработки и что-то вроде: sudo apt install qt5-default;
sudo apt install qtcreator Возможно нужна еще библиотека OpenGL (если её нет). Но в целом на версии SE у вас будут проблемы с тем, что не все пакеты вы сможете установить.

Comment: Как уже сказали выше - `qwt`, причем не требуется установка из сторонних репозиториев, библиотека есть в составе дистрибутива. Если есть возможность вынести графику в отдельное приложение-клиент, то можно использовать `matplotlib`, который есть в средствах разработки.